# How do I vertically align and float to edges images

Tags: html, css

How do I align images inside a nav tag and push them to the edges of the nav element?

From what I've found researching I am trying to use `vertical-align: middle` and `float` but they have no effect on displaying the elements.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/BaajLZm

```
#company-name {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need vertical-align. The "nav" element have "display: flex;".
so set "align-items: center;" into css of "nav" element.

```
nav {
font-family: monospace;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
background: rgb(67, 66, 66);}
```

Comment: Thats awesome Pegah. How do I push them to the edges?

Comment: Use for nav style: justify-content:space-between; and two image in the right hand wrap with a span tag.

Comment: Thanks. The span and justify-content did it.